# Return the correct number of weeks for the Gregorian Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

I have a problem with the calendar that I use to get me a smaller number of weeks for certain months
For example, this happens to me at Sept 2019, where my number is 5 or in July 2018, which is also 5.
How can I fix this?
this is my current code:

```
    private DateTime _calendarDate;
    int numWeeks = NumberOfWeeks(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month);

    private int NumberOfWeeks(int year, int month)
    {
        return NumberOfWeeks(new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)));
    }
    private int NumberOfWeeks(DateTime date)
    {
        var beginningOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

        while (date.Date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
                    date = date.AddDays(1);

        return (int)Math.Truncate(date.Subtract(beginningOfMonth).TotalDays / 7f) + 1;
    }
```

additional information on CultureInfo

[image]

The problem is that it always comes back to me one week less, so my calendar doesn't display it properly and then I get the error,

Here's an example for April 2018 where you give me 5 weeks, and then another one is missing and that's why I'm getting the error

can anyone guess how i could solve this problem?

Comment: It is really nesessary to display exact number of month weeks? It could be better to display 6 weeks for every month.

Comment: Do you want to get the count of complete weeks in the month or the count of calendar weeks in this month, no matter if it is just one day of this week that is in this month?

Comment: @AlexL if it were necessary, I wouldn't ask if it wasn't

Comment: @RedFox I would be happy with any solution of the two, but if I could choose a solution with full weeks, for example, in June 2019 it shows all days until 30, and then July begins, the first week, where it is dependent, would mean enough 5 weeks.

Comment: With the current layout, each month of 31 days where the first day is saturday or sunday and each month of 30 days where the first day is sunday, you have an overflow. So, you need another week (another row). Unless you can `move` the layout (the days' labels are not fixed). If the labels' position is not fixed, then you have 35 days per month, so `(35 - DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month)) / 2` is the position of the first day of the month. So first position of the current month shows `DateTime(Year, Month, 1).DayOfWeek`.  The first cell is 2 or 3 days before this date.

Comment: Ok @Jimi how could I handle this then?

Comment: Well, that's your choice. If you want the first cell of the week to always show monday (culture dependent) and the last sunday (culture dependent), then you have to add a row. Otherwise, as described in the previous comment, from *If the labels' position is not fixed...* onward. In this case, the rows count don't change (if that's important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can use `System.Globalization.Calendar` you can get the count of weeks in a month by using `GetWeekOfYear` for the first and the last day of the month and then calculate the difference (and add 1 to include the first week).
This would change your `NumberOfWeeks()` to the following:

```
private int NumberOfWeeks(DateTime date)
    {
        Calendar calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);


        var week1 = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(firstOfMonth, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        var week2 = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);

        int numberOfWeeks = (week2 - week1) + 1;

        return numberOfWeeks;
    }
```

For your example (April 2018) this will give you 6 as a result and for May 2018 it will give you 5.

[MSDN GetWeekOfYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Extra, this works just fine, thanks a lot for the time and the huge help, you saved my day :)

Comment: This might get a bit weird at the end of a year, when for example december 31 is already in the first week of next year. So if `week2` is less than `week1`, you probably want to do `week2 = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.AddDays(-7), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday) + 1;`

Comment: `GetWeekOfYear()` will return the numbers of weeks in the given year, when the 31st of December is in the first week of the next year. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more mathematical solution:

```
int myYear = 2019, myMonth = 12; // the example for December 2019
var firstMonthDay = new DateTime(myYear, myMonth, 1);
int delta = firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek - System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
if (delta < 0)
    delta += 7;

int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(myYear, myMonth);    
int weekLinesNumber = (int)Math.Ceiling((daysInMonth + delta) / 7F); // the result
```

We count the delta (could be from 0 to 6), this is the number of days from the first day of the week to the first next month day. Then we count the resulting number of the weeks using `Math.Ceiling` function.

In short, we add to the month some delta days at the beginning in order to get new Extra Month block starting from the First Day of a Week (according to the culture). And then we count the total number of the occupied week lines. No need to add `+1` when we use `Math.Ceiling` function.

Comment: I have a problem with your code at December 2018, where it loads 5 lines and prints days to 30, 6 weeks with 31 days doesn't print ..

Comment: It's strange, I have tested, with Monday as first day of week I get 6 lines for 2018.12